# Getting friend_likes in a single API call

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

For a single user of my app, I want to find the likes of all his/her friends. Assuming my app requires the user to approve the app access to the friends_likes [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), is it possible to get the likes of all his/her friends in a single (or a few) API calls? [This article](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/18/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-pull-the-movies-friends-like/) suggests I have to make one call per friend of my user; I'd like to avoid this if possible since one user may have upwards of 1000 friends. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You could do it in one [FQL query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20name%2C%20page_id%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_fan%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%29):

```
SELECT name, page_id 
 FROM page 
 WHERE page_id IN 
  (SELECT page_id 
   FROM page_fan 
   WHERE uid IN 
     (SELECT uid2 FROM 
      friend 
      WHERE uid1 = me()
   )
 )
```